# Composer clones from cache instead of repo

Tags: caching, composer-php

I have two projects I am working on, both were setup as git repos, both use composer.
First project uses second as a library.
I configured composer.json in the following way:

```
... "repositories": [
    {"type": "composer", "url":"http://composer.myrepourl.com/repo/private/"},
]

"require": {
    "second/second": "dev-B-3"
} ...
```

There was no problem pulling the project from a repository for the first time. However now I made some changes in second project, pushed to the repo and now want to have them in first project, but for some reason composer pulls from the cache.

I ran composer clear-cache. I tried deleting: vendor folder, /home/user/.composer/cache, cache inside container /root/.composer/, but it still finds a way to clone the second project from cache instead of pulling it from repo.

Any ideas on how to force composer to always pull from repo instead of cloning from cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found a solution:

```
sudo rm -r /home/user/project/vendor
cd %wherever_your_docker_is%
docker-compose stop
docker-compose rm
docker-compose up -d
composer update
```

Answer (score 8):

Run

```
$ composer install --prefer-source
```

Alternatively, specify your preferred installation method in `composer.json` generally:

```
{
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "source"
    }
}
```

or specifically for the desired dependency

generally:

```
{
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "vendor/package": "source",
            "*": "dist"
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, see:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#preferred-install

Comment: you may also need to add `--no-cache` (and to delete the package from vendor directory  beforehand)

Comment: Doing this I still had `- Syncing studiopress/genesis-connect-woocommerce (dev-develop 2ac4dfe) into cache` in the Bitbucket pipeline. Still looking for way to bypass cache and download again.

Answer (score 2):

you should run

```
composer clear-cache
```

then

```
composer update --prefer-source
```